# Change videos on buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a challenging question that might be interest you. I have four mp4 videos of a cartoon character doing emotes etc. I want to turn on a toggle switch and the first mp4 video (intro) along with 3 buttons will appear. After that I want to press any of the 3 buttons and a different video will play each time. When I turn the toggle switch of everything will disappear. Any ideas how to write the code?

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: Check out and go through some javascript/html/css tutorials available online. There are tons of tutorial videos in youtube too. After you're comfortable with the languages, try to implement the above 'challenge' and if it doesn't work, you can come back here post what you have tried so far and we can help you out from there.

Comment: StackOverflow's official [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) Documentation. Cheers Vangelis.

Answer (score 0):

Bind all videos in list with button and then check which button clicked using on click event

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    //append the video 
})

$('#btn2').click(function(){
    //append the video 
})

$('#btn3').click(function(){
    //append the video 
})
```